# mysql and php ... i want to know about optimization

Tags: php, mysql

in optimization in mysql  wat are the topics i have to cover? there are so many things in that .......

Comment: Asking such a generalized question is akin to asking "how do I make code run faster" without providing the problem or any code. When you have examples of code you're interested in optimizing, post those here instead and you're likely to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

First - analyze your code/sql to find slow places.

Second - optimize only these slow places, and don't try to optimize what is already fast, or never runs.

Answer (score 1):

Some MySQL Optimization Hints:

**SQL_NO_CACHE**

The SQL_NO_CACHE hint turns off MySQL's builtin query caching mechanism for a particular query. You can help MySQL make the query cache more efficent by using this hint on queries that are highly dynamic (such as a keyword search, or a report that only runs nightly). Make sure query caching is turned on otherwise there is no need for this command.

**SQL_CACHE**

If you have setup MySQL Query Caching to explicit mode (set query_cache_type = 2) then you can use the SQL_CACHE hint to tell MySQL which queries to cache.

**HIGH_PRIORITY**

The HIGH_PRIORITY hint can be used on SELECT or INSERT statements to let MySQL know that this is a high priority query. This hint will basically allow the query to skip in line.

**LOW_PRIORITY**

The LOW_PRIORITY hint can be used on INSERT and UPDATE statements. If you use the LOW_PRIORITY keyword, execution of the query is delayed until no other clients are reading from the table. This means that you may wait a LONG time, or forever on servers with a heavy read volume.

**INSERT DELAYED**

An INSERT LOW_PRIORITY statment will not return until the statement has been executed, which could possibly be forever. Instead you can use an INSERT DELAYED statement. It will return immediately, but it will still wait until other clients have closed the table before executing the statement.

Note: INSERT DELAYED only works on MyISAM, MEMORY, and ARCHIVE tables.
STRAIGHT_JOIN

This hint will tell MySQL to join the tables in the order that they are specified in the FROM clause.

Use EXPLAIN to make sure that MySQL has not already figured out the optimal join order. And if you specify an ill order you can make MySQL do a lot more work than it needs to.
SQL_BUFFER_RESULT

This hint tells MySQL to put the result of the query into a temporary table. This will free up a table lock while the resultset is being sent to the client. So you would only want to use this on large result sets.

**SQL_BIG_RESULT**

The SQL_BIG_RESULT hint can be used with DISTINCT and GROUP BY SELECT statements. It as you might guess, tells MySQL that the result set will be big. According to the MySQL documentation, if invoked

```
MySQL directly uses disk-based temporary tables if needed, and prefers sorting to using a temporary table with a key on the GROUP BY elements.
```

**SQL_SMALL_RESULT**

AS you might guess this is pretty much the opposite of SQL_BIG_RESULT. When enabled MySQL uses fast temporary tables to store the resulting table instead of using sorting. Since this is typically the default route of the optimizer, this hint is often not needed.

Comment: an url of mysql docs page would be better than a huge copy-paste

Comment: i like copy and pastes, makes things more digestible